# Where to ask a question about image processing with MATLAB?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about image processing using MATLAB. Where should I raise the question? Programmer or Photography?

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow would seem like [a good choice...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+image-processing)